# tlcontrib not verified: pubkey missing

Tags: tlmgr, contribute

I've followed this [doc](https://contrib.texlive.info/) to add tlcontrib repo but i got the following error

```
tlcontrib = http://contrib.texlive.info/current (not verified: pubkey missing)
```

what went wrong?

**Edit:** i read [this](https://texlive.info/verification.html) and knew that

> The repository is signed, but the respective public key has not been imported into tlmgr's gpg key database. Please consult with the maintainer of the repository to receive the key, and then call

i think it's an official one so i don't think this is valid in my case.

**Note:** i'm a total beginner "just installed Tex Live today"

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was there in [this](https://contrib.texlive.info/) documentation already i guess they should add the verification step a little bit earlier anyway the solution is actually the next step