# Package repository not verified: pubkey missing

Tags: packages, texlive

Am getting the following error when I try to do `tlmgr install package`:

```
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: pubkey missing)
```

It appears I need to get the keys somewhere, but I haven't been able to find them on CTAN. Where else can I find them?

If it's any use, I just updated my system on Arch, so maybe some other fellow Arch users had a similar problem?

Comment: Potentially related: [Unable to connect via tlmgr - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483613/unable-to-connect-via-tlmgr) (actually it doesn't help...) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541955/tlcontrib-not-verified-pubkey-missing (doesn't help either...) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528634/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5

Comment: there's also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537376/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5-for-main-repository/537379#537379

Comment: Okay I encounter this issue myself, apparently the error is not fatal, maybe there's some other line after it like `tlmgr install: package ⟨package⟩ not present in repository.` which obviously explains what's going on. Not sure if it's the case here because of lack of detail